# Select in VBA Error 1004

Tags: vba

boa noite

Minha planilha possui um botão onde o mesmo irá abrir uma Form. Esse Form possui um LIST VIEW onde é carregado os dados de uma sheet da planilha. Até ai tudo bem. Também no Form possui um botão para filtrar os dados do LIST VIEW, com base nos valores selecionados em um COMBO BOX. O código abaixo é do botão de filtro, porém, quando o mesmo executa, apresenta erro na linha ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILTRO").Range(RangeDeValores).Select

Saberiam me dizer o por que disso?

Segue abaixo o código do botão filtrar:

```
Private Sub btnFiltrar_Click()

    'LIMPA A ABA FILTRO
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILTRO").Cells.Clear

    'COPIA A ABA BASE DE DADOS PARA A ABA FILTRO
    Dim ultima_linha As Long
    ultima_linha = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE_DADOS").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim RangeDeValores As String
    RangeDeValores = "A1:G" & CStr(ultima_linha)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE_DADOS").Range(RangeDeValores).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILTRO").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'FILTRA NA ABA FILTRO OS ITENS SELECIONADOS NO LIST BOX DE ITENS
    Dim listaItens(99999)

    For i = 0 To fPesquisar.lbItens.ListCount - 1
        If fPesquisar.lbItens.Selected(i) = True Then
            listaItens(i) = fPesquisar.lbItens.List(i)
        End If
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILTRO").Range(RangeDeValores).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=listaItens, Operator:=xlFilterValues


End Sub
```

Comment: Tentou dar um `debug.print RangeDeValores`para ver o que tem ai?

Comment: Você não precisa da variavel RangeDeValores (Acho que tá dando problema por ser string)
Substitua `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE_DADOS").Range(RangeDeValores).Copy` por `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE_DADOS").Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(ultima_linha,7)).Copy`